# docker-compose.yaml File - How to denote special characters in a password?

Tags: docker-compose, yaml

I'm creating a docker-compose.yml file and need to have special characters for the database password but docker-compose doesn't understand it properly.

How can I use special characters for my password field in this .yaml file?

```
wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user_1
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: '$1234abcd' # Special characters aren't being recognized here
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: db1
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $1234abcd
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: '$1234abcd'
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "$1234abcd"
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "\$1234abcd"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To escape the $ you need to use two, in your case it would be something like $$1234abcd.

If using only one compose will try to interpret it as an environment variable, explained here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution